# rvalue reference (&&) in for each loop

Tags: c++

Читаю книгу **Адитья Бхаргава "Грокаем алгоритмы**". В одной из глав говорится про **графы** и алгоритм для нахождения **кратчайшего пути**. Так как учу с++, у автора на github залит собственный код https://github.com/egonSchiele/grokking_algorithms/blob/master/06_breadth-first_search/c%2B%2B11/01_breadth-first_search.cpp.

Прошу, **умоляю** объяснить как работает данный участок кода

```
 for (auto&& friend_name : graph.find(name)->second)
        search_queue.push(friend_name);
```

А именно почему решили использовать rvalue и почему **graph.find(name)->second** вообще работает :D.

Спасибо.

Comment: Кстати данный код по ссылке не работает, так как там объект из очереди удаляется раньше, чем проверяется функцией is_seller. Строка пустая, поэтому name.back() выбросит исключение.

Comment: `auto&&` - "универсальная ссылка", погуглите про них.` *"почему `graph.find(name)->second` вообще работает"* А почему нет? Но правильнее было бы `graph.at(name)` - чтобы на отсутствующий элемент было исключение, а не неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, что `graph.find(name)` по ключу `name` возвращает итератор на элемент(Но тут проблема, если такого ключа нет, и операция с итератором станет недействительной). Как и всегда, нужно применить оператор `->`, чтобы через итератор ссылаться на элемент контейнера. А типом элемента является пара(ключ(first), значение( second)).  В итоге:

```
graph.find(name)->second
```

что эквивалентно выражению:
`graph[name]`, c  разницей, что  последнее является lvalue ссылкой, а ее нельзя привязать к rvalue

выдаст значение(в данном случаи вектор) по ключу .

Чтобы избежать накладных расходов при копировании вектора  в очередь, его(владение ресурсами) перемещают, передавая в функцию член `push`  r-value ссылку, поскольку  очередь нужна как временное хранилище.

P.S. Механизм семантики перемещения, когда и как использовать лучше изучать по учебникам

Comment: Не, вектор не перемещается - `auto&&` втихую превращается в lvalue-ссылку. И `graph.find(name)->second`, и `graph[name]` возвращают lvalue (но второй вариант вставляет пустой элемент в мапу, если его там раньше не было).